# Application stopped unexpectedly Android Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I followed few tutorials and I found this error unsolved.
Here are my code. My application was stopped unexpectedly every time I run after 2 seconds (pre-set timer)

The error was: The application Test(process com.juicy.test) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. It prompts on the AVD.

> W/dalvikvm(281): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x4001d800)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(281): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No
>   Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.juicy.test.MAINACTIVITY }
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(281):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(281):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(281):    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(281):    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(281):    at com.juicy.test.Tree$1.run(Tree.java:24)**

**Tree.xml**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tree);

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.juicy.test.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.juicy.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Tree"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.juicy.test.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.juicy.test;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your error logs

Comment: post your logcat so that we may know where the error is...

Comment: Sorry guys, i've added those logcat errors into my post.

Comment: @Danzeeeee look at the answers I hope your activity will now work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file you are starting two activities at a time so either remove this code from .MainActivity or .Tree activity ..

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.juicy.test.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

hope this helps ...

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Changed either 1 to DEFAULT and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you have  set **two launchers** in manifest file. Here launcher means which activity to start at first so there can be only one launcher.

Whenever you are launching your application it searches for activity containing launcher from top in manifest  and opens the first activity containing Launcher(which is .Tree in your case). Remember to set category other than launcher for other activities.

In AndroidManifest.xml change application containing MainActivity to  **android.intent.category.DEFAULT**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.juicy.test.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Note:** You could also remove the category field as it is set as default when you donot specify any category

Answer (score 0):

Open the manifest and Ctrl click on the activity class name. If the class file doesn't open, the chances are, it is not mapped correctly. This may lead to this error.